# Robot FrameworK: Unable to run robot scripts in ie, same script ran perfectly alright previous day, this is recurring now

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

Unable to run Robot Framework scripts:

Zoom size set to 100% but still this issue, same script ran yesterday perfectly fine. All of a sudden its failing to launch, now this issue is faced multiple times.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And you changed nothing at all? Everything is EXACTLY the same as yesterday?

Comment: yes, no changes at all.. same script ran perfectly, atleast it didnt had any issues in launching IE at first place.

Comment: Please don't show screenshots of errors. Copy and paste the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

You should first troubleshoot IEDriverServer, by launching it and then access with IE to http://localhost: or http://127.0.0.1:. You should see:

```
This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.
```

The port you tried, 52920 could be blocked.